# why do i get an error on doInBackground

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
protected S3TaskResult doInBackground(Uri... uris) {


        if (uris == null || uris.length != 1) {
            return null;
        }

        // The file location of the image selected.
        Uri selectedImage = uris[0];


        ContentResolver resolver = activity.getContentResolver();
        String fileSizeColumn[] = {OpenableColumns.SIZE}; 

        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(selectedImage,
                fileSizeColumn, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        // If the size is unknown, the value stored is null.  But since an int can't be
        // null in java, the behavior is implementation-specific, which is just a fancy
        // term for "unpredictable".  So as a rule, check if it's null before assigning
        // to an int.  This will happen often:  The storage API allows for remote
        // files, whose size might not be locally known.
        String size = null;
        if (!cursor.isNull(sizeIndex)) {
            // Technically the column stores an int, but cursor.getString will do the
            // conversion automatically.
            size = cursor.getString(sizeIndex);
        } 

        cursor.close();

        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentType(resolver.getType(selectedImage));
        if(size != null){
            metadata.setContentLength(Long.parseLong(size));
        }

        S3TaskResult result = new S3TaskResult();

        // Put the image data into S3.
        try {
            s3ClientPasado.createBucket(Constants.getPictureBucket());

            PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(
                    Constants.getPictureBucket(), Constants.PICTURE_NAME,
                    resolver.openInputStream(selectedImage),metadata);
            s3ClientPasado.putObject(por);
        } catch (Exception exception) {

            result.setErrorMessage(exception.getMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

It says that an error occurred while executing doInBackground()

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please post full stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when the Uri I passed turned to be of null value.
The problem occurred in the `resolver.query` method.
You should post the rest of your code so we could understand it better.

For example - if you are using this code after getting an image from the camera please post how you invoke the camera intent and how you get the Uri.

Good luck.